# How to create overlapping frames of input signal for stft using HDL coder for FPGA implementation?

Tags: matlab, fft, stft, simulink

I want to implement stft on FPGA. For this purpose I use HDL coder and the problem is I have no idea how to create overlapping frames of data for further FFT. In my example I want to use 256 frame length and 128 hop length. I think it is possible to solve this problem using some state machine and dual-port ram, but, unfortunately, I don't have much experience, so I ask anyone to push me towards the solution or propose some idea.

Comment: If you're using HDL coder, you should use the buffer block from Simulink. You can specify the buffer length AND the overlap

Comment: Yeah, good idea, but I cannot generate hdl from it, it doen't supported

Comment: I did a lot of FPGA design in the past. What's the FFT block you wanted to use in Simulink?

Comment: For example FFT HDL Optimized from DSP HDL Toolbox.

Comment: it seems to be a streaming block? What you want to do is not streaming.

Comment: I understand this, so maybe there is a way to restructure streaming data into overlapping frames using ram(or something else) and then sent it to fft block. Something like this https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/8/12/1533/pdf

Comment: You could probably do it with a delay line. I'll try to show you a solution tonight or tomorrow

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to look at this

Comment: Any suggestions?